# network error 500 while trying codeigniter controller action using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have  an admin controller and inside that i have a processReq function.Here i have a button which will access the controller action on click.But whenever i click the button it gives me an error saying

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
>   http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/index.php/Admin/processReq"

i have my index.php hidden using htaccess file

**admin controller:**

```
   class Admin extends CI_Controller{

         public function processReq(){
             $status=$this->item->post('status');
             echo $status;
         }

   }
```

**and ajax request is :**

```
<button type="button" data-id='approved' class="btn btn-success approved buttons"  style="margin-right:15px;font-weight:bold;">Approve</button>
```

ajax:

```
$(".buttons").click(function(event){
     var status=$(this).data('id');
     $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Admin/processReq'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'status': status
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Is there an error logged in your error log? For Apache that will probably be in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: You have syntax error.It should be like this `url: '<?php echo base_url("Admin/processReq"); ?>',` Note single and double quote.

Answer (score 2):

Change URL this

```
url: '<?php echo base_url('Admin/processReq'); ?>',
```

to this

```
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Admin/processReq',
```

> Adding **index.php** to URL

---

Change this to

```
$status=$this->item->post('status');
```

This

```
$status=$this->input->post('status');
```

---

**EDIT 01**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".buttons").click(function(event)
        {
            var status=$(this).data('id');
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/processReq",
                    data:{ status:status},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert('success');
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have set $config['base_url'] ?

Comment: it has http..when i post in comment http gets removed...after  i change item to input ..error gone...but reqeust not accessing the controller....i tried to echo inside the function of controller,,,it is not triggering..that means ajax request not invoking the controller action .. it

Comment: Try `Admin` to `admin` and try

Comment: do i need to have a page created  called processReq.php ?

Comment: Comment all the code in `$(".buttons").click(function(event){` and just add `alert('here');` and check the output. **I think your AJAX not triggering**

Comment: Try `alert('status')` and post output

Comment: if i comment out ajax code and apply alert('status') inside click event it alerts the string 'status'

Comment: sorry its `alert(status)`

Comment: it is also ok....status alerts the value assigned to it...the data-id from button

Comment: Where are you seeing the error 500, in the browser console? I would comment out what you have in your processReq() function and simply add echo 'working'; or an error_log() statement. You can also add error: function(x,y,z) { console.log(x,y,z); }, above your success key in the ajax call

Comment: ok...it alerts success...but not going inside the controller action...i know because i have  created a view load inside processReq controller..if it entered the controller it would load the view

Comment: Above ajax should work. Cz its from my codes. It works well

Comment: what about the function enclosing...is it necessary ,,,i omitted that in my code

Comment: is there any token related issue..like csrf or something ?

Comment: May be. you have to trigger that whats wrong in your end

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have Syntax error.

`url: '<?php echo base_url("Admin/processReq"); ?>',`
should be like this

```
url: '<?php echo base_url("Admin/processReq"); ?>',
```

Second if you are using .htaccess to hide index.php from url. That means it is not producing right url as you see index.php at your ajax request.

Go to your application/config.php and set base_url like this

```
$config['base_url'] = ' http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/';
```

and set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
//remove index.php from this line
//whatever you set here it will be included to your base_url when you use site_url function.
```